# Trigger more than one URL after IntelliJ Run configuration is run

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a Run configuration which builds an exploded web app, deploys it to tomcat, and opens the home page after that. However, I want to hit a few URLs to set some state in the app before opening the home page (Or after opening the homepage; it does not matter). Is there a way to trigger a few URL hits after the run configuration? This feature would be similar to "before launch." Instead, it would be "after launch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature at the moment, you can [vote for the related feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132501).

It's not as simple as it looks since it's not clear what would trigger the **after** event. The app server doesn't exit/terminate, but is still running, therefore it's not possible to use another run configuration with your app server added in its **Before launch** steps, otherwise you could create a **Shell script** configuration that would call `curl`/`wget`.

For the app server the proper **after** event would be the moment when the artifact deployment is complete which requires the tight integration with this specific app server so that IDE knows the exact moment when it happens and allows to call some custom action.

This might be possible with the custom plug-in as IDE already knows when the artifact deployment is complete.

A really hacky workaround would be to run some tiny HTTP server and open its URL from the IDE instead of your real app server. This custom server would call the URLs/APIs you need and then open a browser for your real app URL.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. Alternatively, I tried creating a shell script run configuration which uses the webapp in the "before" section, but the shell script never executes when the webapp deploy is done. Is there a trick to making that work?

Comment: Sorry you're right you did just answer that. My bad for skimming through that